# I have found some spam links that are only visible on mobile devices, and I can't find where is the script that contains this spam links

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla, spam

So I have this problem only when I see the page on mobile devices! I tried to find the spam links through the computer but I can't find them anywhere.
 I think it's in the K2 Plugins but I don't know on which one. I'll paste some of the code here I've found with the spam links:

```
<!-- Plugins: AfterDisplayTitle -->

<!-- K2 Plugins: K2AfterDisplayTitle -->
<div class="itemBody">
    <!-- Plugins: BeforeDisplayContent -->
    <div id="js-pc">
        <a href="http://portalinfo.org/" target="_blank" title="русский бизнес за границей">русский бизнес за границей</a><br>
        <a href="http://travels-world.net/" target="_blank" title="записки туриста">записки туриста</a>
    </div>
    <!-- K2 Plugins: K2BeforeDisplayContent -->

    <!-- Plugins: AfterDisplayContent -->
    <div id="js-pc">
        <a href="http://realyrock.net/" target="_blank" title="обзоры музыкальных групп">обзоры музыкальных групп</a><br>
        <a href="http://magical-place.ru/" target="_blank" title="спортивный туризм">спортивный туризм</a>
    </div>
    <!-- K2 Plugins: K2AfterDisplayContent -->

<div class="clr"></div>

<!--End Item Rating -->
</div>
```

So these are the Russian spam links I can't delete.

Comment: Are you sure these links are generated by a plugin and not by your cellphone? Does these links appear when accessed from another cellphone? With few information like this we couldn't be able to help you, if you have a live version where this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked my answer @Laura-Juncu ? Did it helped?

Answer (score 1):

**A solution is:**
 1. Start search in all files of your website by the next keyoword: **base64_decode**
 2. You must find something like the next:

`<?php $mgp='PGRpdiBpZD0iaXQtc24iPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9qb29tbGEtbWFzdGVyLm9yZy8iIHRhcmdldD0iX2JsYW5rIiB0aXRsZT0i0LrQsNC6INGB0L7Qt9C00LDRgtGMINGB0LDQudGCINC90LAgSm9vbWxhIDMiPtC60LDQuiDRgdC+0LfQtNCw0YLRjCDRgdCw0LnRgiDQvdCwIEpvb21sYSAzPC9hPjwvZGl2Pg=='; echo base64_decode($mgp);?>`

3. The next symptom is: this string stand right from the base code
4. Delete this string carefully and enjoy :)

Hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably these links are being generated through a jquery/js code and by media queries as well, this is why the reason they only appear on mobile devices. Perhaps if you dig on these plugin's code you'd find where this is being generated assuming it's on these plugins.
 Somewhere on your plugin's CSS code, must be something like this example:

```
#js-pc {
    display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
    #js-pc {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

the code above make the links only visible on screens smaller than 600px width, 
but you can overwrite this action through your main CSS file as well, forcing this links to not be displayed with `display:none !important;`. It will be something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    #js-pc {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

The media query above depends on which size they are appearing but if it's only on mobile devices I think this will fix the problem.
Here's an example of what your **[website is showing](http://jsfiddle.net/r2fy58tz/)** right now, and **[this is your fix](http://jsfiddle.net/r2fy58tz/1/)**

Comment: You're welcome @LauraJuncu =)
If you have some time to spare please consider marking my answer as correct